# How do you query a database from JSP Form Data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am in need of assistance. I am trying to write a basic form that populates a drop-down list and based on what you select, it queries the database. However, I cannot get it to do it, It just receives all the queries. I am at a loss so if you have any helpful advice or helpful links, that'd be great. I really need to learn Spring MVC, and Hibernate combined. thanks!

HomeController Code: (This controller populates the list)

```
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */

@Controller
public class SearchController {

@Autowired
FilmBo filmBo;

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, ModelMap model) {

    Selection selection = new Selection();
    model.addAttribute("selection", selection);
    return "search";
}



@ModelAttribute("categoryList")
public List<String> populateList(){
    List<String> categoryList = filmBo.searchByCategory("");
    return categoryList;
}

}
```

Here is the MainController that the form upon submit gets sent to:

```
public class FilmController {
private static final Logger logger =           LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchController.class);

@Autowired
FilmBo filmBo;



@RequestMapping(value = "/films", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model,      @RequestParam(value="title",required=false) String title,
        @RequestParam(value="category",required=false) String category) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
    List<Film> filmList = filmBo.searchByTitle(title);
    logger.info("filmList: " + filmList);
    model.addAttribute("filmList", filmList);

    List<String> filmCategory = filmBo.searchByCategory(category);
    logger.info("filmCategory: " + filmCategory);
    model.addAttribute("filmCategory",filmCategory);

    return "films";
}
}
```

Here is my jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="form">
    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/films"
        method="GET" commandName="selection">
        Film Title<input type="text" name="title">
        <br>
        Select a Film Category:<br>
        <form:select path="selection">
            <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
            <form:options name="category" items="${categoryList}" />
        </form:select>

        <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit Name</button>
    </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clarified my question. I'm terrible at wording things properly.

Comment: Are you missing your `@Controller` annotation on the `FilmController` class? Also your Logger is being created with `SearchController` in the `FilmController` class. Thirdly, what is actually happening? Is the JSP showing up blank? Are you getting an exception? We need more information about what the problem you are actually encountering is. Perhaps clarify what you mean by "I cannot get it to do it, It just receives all the queries" because I don't understand what you mean